# How can I successfully loop this Boolean to output a product with less than color quantity?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

This is my firestore with its following data. I want my code to check if the colorMap which is the color quantity then output the prodName which is the product with less than 10 color quantity.

![Firestore][1]

And this is the error that I'm getting in my code.

[image: error]

> This is the code. I'm not sure if the .filter is actually working.

```
{details.filter(details => details.color < 10).map((val) => {
        return (<ul>
                <li key={val.id}><p className="pt-2">{val.prodName} </p></li>
                </ul>
        );

      })}
```

> This is my reference for getting the data in the firebase.

```
  const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);

  const userData = async () => {
  
  const q = query(collection(db, "products"));

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
    ...doc.data(),
    id: doc.id,
  }));
  setDetails(data);
};
```

> If you guys know how to do this with using the if statement. Please refer it to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd parameter in [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#syntax) is the index of element and not an object. Try using the document ID as the key instead:

```
key={val.id} // instead of {item.id}
```

Also you should create 1 list and then add list items using map instead of creating a new list for each item:

```
<ul>
{details.filter((detail) => Object.values(detail.colorMap).find(c => c < 10)).map((val, item) => {
        return (<li key={val.id}><p className="pt-2">{val.prodName} </p></li>);
})}
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried it, and it still has the same error.

Comment: @ImranNoir have you tried restarting the dev server? Also are you share the warning is from the code you provided then? You are referring to duplicate key warning right?

Comment: Dev server? As in like restarting the app and run the program again? If so, yea I've tried that. Yea its the same error as the one here. I dunno why the warning is about the unique key even there is a key already.

Comment: @ImranNoir I believe you are trying to add list items in a single list. Can you try updating your code as in my updated answer? Currently you are creating a new list for each item

Comment: I'm trying to output the prodName which is the product name in a list form. That have a color quantity less than 10 which is the colorMap.

Comment: @ImranNoir I can see a field `colorMap`. So like are you filtering by any 1 color or so? or total of all colors is less than 10?

Comment: I'm thinking like filtering each color that are less than 10 in each product. If the code detects a color less than 10 it would output its product name.

Comment: @ImranNoir can you try out the updated answer? You can filter out items where value of any color is less than 10

Comment: Yea, I've tried it still the same error and a new one where it says failed to load resource. The way I did the .filter is it okay or correct?

Comment: I'll reply to you tomorrow. Its pretty late right now.

Comment: @ImranNoir if you are trying out code in my answer that works. Try restarting dev server and ensure that you have only 1 <ul> as in my answer.

Comment: It worked! Thanks you so much man, I appreciate it. I've been working on this for a week now.

Comment: Can you tell me how if I want to output the color and the stock number too?  Right beside the product name

Comment: You can try something like `return (<li key={val.id}><p className="pt-2">{val.prodName} 
 {Object.entries(val.colorMap).map((c) => (<p>{c[0]}{c[1]}</p>))}</p></li>);`

Comment: It might be best to post a new question with relevant details if you have a new question so it'll get more visibility.

Comment: Okay man I'll try it.  Thanks. I'll post a new question if ever.